# Installing GeoServer through Tomcat

Tags: geoserver, installation, tomcat

I have had issues with this installation all throughout but was able to fix the issues until this one.

After I deploy the web archive file and try to start GeoServer through the manager app nothing seems to be happening. In the Tomcat logfile I get the following error message:

```
19-Dec-2021 12:19:31.288 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-40] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/geoserver] startup failed due to previous errors

19-Dec-2021 12:23:41.675 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

19-Dec-2021 12:23:41.685 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

19-Dec-2021 12:23:41.685 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/geoserver] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I tried adding this in the conf/server.xml

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" driverManagerProtection="false" />
```

GeoServer is installed in its entirety in the webapps folder.
The previous error. could this be referring to an earlier installation of GeoServer? I have removed all previous files related to geoserver.

Here are the complete log files:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kc5tn5lXq1Y52QHpc7vX2Z-iGM4N-bhs?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: `due to previous errors` implies you need to look further up the log file to find out what went wrong. It might also be useful to tell us what else went wrong and how you "fixed" it

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant part of the log

Answer (score 1):

Another process is already using the port you are attempting to open tomcat on.